# The set of elements that are members of this set?

Tags: computability, decidability

Can a set refer to itself in its own definition / define itself in the above way? Is the above set a set?

variant: A word w is a member of a language L iff it is a member of language L, ie. the condition for w's membership to L is that it be a member of L.

Is there a proof for the fact that this language is undecidable due to this self-reference, due to the fact that this language might not be a set? Can you say a language is not decidable because it is not defined? Or is simply outside the bounds of computability theory? Or is this a property of every language and is totally fine?

Comment: I dont think it will fly in ZFC because of the axiom schema of specification. In order to define a set $S = \{a | a \in S\}$ would require that the set $S$ already be defined / exist. In the case that $S$ was previously defined its just redundant.

Answer (score 2):

> Can a set refer to itself in its own definition / define itself in the above way?

No. This is what's known as an [impredicative definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity). This is, instead, a true statement about all sets, distinguishing none over any of the others.

In certain circumstances, we do define things *implicitly*, meaning we provide some conditions for an object to satisfy, argue that there is a unique object satisfying these criteria, and then proceed to use this unique object in our calculations. Probably the most elementary examples of this are recurrence relations, e.g.
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}, \quad x_1 = x_2 = 1.$$
Note that, as a definition, this would be impredicative. But, it can be proven (with induction) that there is one and only one sequence whose terms satisfy these conditions. This is how we typically define the Fibonacci sequence, not with a formula, but implicitly, with this relationship!

But, as I said, your example cannot function as a definition, simply because every set satisfies this condition; you don't get the uniqueness required for an implicit definition.

I wouldn't say this makes $L$ undecidable, so much as undefined.

Comment: If L is undefined is it undecidable? No matter how trivial this may sound this is what I'm looking for. Is there any way to say because of the fact L is not a set L is not computable? To give some background, in this proof, if I make a certain assumption then membership to L (for a certain subset of inputs) depends on membership to L. this precise fact causes that assumption to be faulty. I just need a formal way of saying that this self-reference has mucked things up and L is no longer decidable under this assumption.

Comment: As I said in my last line, I'd say it's "undefined". In response to the question, "Is it undecidable?", I would answer (rather glibly) "Is what undecidable?". It'd be like me asking whether the Fyshwyck-Xu language is undecidable (a name I made up on the spot). There's no meaning to the question, until I actually tell you what the language is. I could even tell you that it's the language of words in the Fyshwyck-Xu language, but that wouldn't enlighten you at all as to what the language consists of.

Comment: So, if i make an assumption in my proof and arrive in the situation that my language L now is "undefined' can i end that branch of the proof saying that this assumptions arrives us at a contradiction, because L is now undefined? I'm wondering what to do, now that Im at this point and this language L has reared its head.

Comment: No, not really; there's no contradiction. Whatever object you're trying to work with is not defined in whatever subcase you find yourself in. Whatever condition $L$ satisfies, which you are taking as an implicit definition, doesn't uniquely define $L$ in whatever case you're in. That's about as far as I can comment without further context.

Comment: For further context: my assumption is that L is decidable (in a certain complexity class C actually). Then because of the way the rest of L is constructed, if this assumption is true, then for certain arguments, their membership to L depends on membership to L. Then, now, because i assumed that L is decidable this leads to L being undefinable in the way that we are discussing. Is my assumption that L is decidable (or in this certain complexity class) compatible with the conclusion that L is undefinable? I would assume not because L can't be in a specific set of languages if it is "other"?

Comment: OK, so it sounds to me like you have a certain condition on languages $L$, and that every decidable $L$ satisfies this condition. That is, whatever class of languages you're trying to define includes every decidable language. If, on the other hand, you're trying to define a specific language implicitly based on a condition, then it sounds like this condition doesn't define a language, because it is satisfied by all decidable languages. In no circumstances should you be able to *prove* an object is undefined, as it is simply out of the scope of the logical framework.

Comment: Yes, it's closer to the first. The conclusion that i come to: L is undefinable, follows from the assumption: L is in some enumerable class of languages. Is this a contradiction? Can a language  be both undefinable and decidable at the same time? I would assume that no language that is in the set of decidable languages (or in any class of decidable languages) is undefinable. Is this something that needs to be proved or is this just true by definition--the class of decidable languages is built from normally definable languages and an undefinable language is just outside?

Comment: In the first case, this condition on $L$ is not the definition of $L$, but just a condition that distinguishes certain languages over others. If this condition is satisfied (albeit trivially) for decidable languages, then it simply means that decidable languages all satisfy this condition. It's not a contradiction, and it's not the definition of the language. It just says that, no matter what decidable language you're considering (with its own separate definition), it will be satisfy this condition.

Comment: As I said briefly before, you cannot logically argue whether or not an object you're working with is defined. You can assume the existence of something satisfying certain conditions, and perhaps come to a contradiction, but you cannot conclude that something is undefined. It is simply not in the logical framework. As soon as you start reasoning with something, it has to have some kind of definition. Maybe not as an explicit object, but certainly an object satisfying certain conditions.

Answer (score 2):

No, this doesn't work.

The key point is that definitions are really *statements*. When we say "Let $X$ be the *foo* that *blah*s," we're implicitly claiming that there is exactly one *foo* that *blah*s - and *then* we're deciding to give it the name "$X$." That second part doesn't work without the first part.

The problem with the "definition" you give is that the property "Is the set of all things in this set" **does not** pin down a unique set, since every set satisfies it. (Similarly, "The set of all things which are elements of this set iff they are not elements of this set" doesn't work as a definition since *no* set has the relevant property.)

Computability does not come into this; it doesn't make sense to ask whether "this set" has any property at all, since it hasn't been specified. We can ask whether *some* sets satisfying the relevant property are decidable (or whatever), but it doesn't make sense to ask whether *the* set satisfying the relevant property is decidable (or whatever) until we've proved that there is in fact exactly one such set: is "The prime less than $10$" even or odd?

On the other hand, there are some apparently-self-referential "definitions" which are actually valid *(ignoring predicativity issues - I'm talking purely classically here)*. For example,

> The set of all objects which are in this set if and only if they are not in this set

**can** actually be construed as a meaningful definition: there is exactly one set $X$ with the property $$X=\{a: a\in X\leftrightarrow a\not\in X\},$$ namely the emptyset.